# Recursive directory listing of /proc

Tags: permissions, directory, ls, proc

I'm trying to obtain a recursive directory listing of my filesystem using the command

```
$ ls -alRc
```

from root directory.

Everything is running fine except the `/proc` directory listing, which results in the following errors:

```
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/186/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/186/task/186/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/187/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/187/task/187/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/188/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/188/task/188/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/189/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/189/task/189/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/19/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/19/task/19/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/190/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/190/task/190/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/191/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/191/task/191/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/192/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/192/task/192/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/193/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/193/task/193/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/194/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/194/task/194/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/195/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/195/task/195/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/196/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/196/task/196/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/197/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/197/task/197/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/198/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/198/task/198/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/199/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/199/task/199/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2/task/2/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/20/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/20/task/20/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/200/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/200/task/200/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/201/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/201/task/201/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/202/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/202/task/202/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/203/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/203/task/203/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/204/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/204/task/204/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/205/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/205/task/205/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/206/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/206/task/206/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/207/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/207/task/207/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/208/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/208/task/208/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/209/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/209/task/209/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/21/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/21/task/21/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/210/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/210/task/210/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/211/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/211/task/211/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/212/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/212/task/212/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/213/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/213/task/213/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/214/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/214/task/214/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/215/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/215/task/215/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/216/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/216/task/216/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/217/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/217/task/217/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/218/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/218/task/218/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/219/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/219/task/219/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/22/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/22/task/22/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/220/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/220/task/220/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/221/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/221/task/221/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/222/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/222/task/222/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/223/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/223/task/223/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/224/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/224/task/224/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/225/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/225/task/225/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/226/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/226/task/226/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/227/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/227/task/227/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/228/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/228/task/228/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/229/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/229/task/229/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/23/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/23/task/23/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/230/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/230/task/230/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/231/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/231/task/231/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/232/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/232/task/232/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/233/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/233/task/233/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/234/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/234/task/234/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/235/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/235/task/235/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/236/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/236/task/236/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/237/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/237/task/237/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/238/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/238/task/238/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/239/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/239/task/239/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/24/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/24/task/24/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/240/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/240/task/240/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/241/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/241/task/241/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/242/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/242/task/242/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/243/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/243/task/243/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/244/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/244/task/244/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/245/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/245/task/245/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/246/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/246/task/246/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/247/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/247/task/247/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/248/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/248/task/248/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/249/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/249/task/249/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/25/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/25/task/25/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/250/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/250/task/250/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/251/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/251/task/251/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/252/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/252/task/252/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/253/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/253/task/253/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/254/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/254/task/254/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/255/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/255/task/255/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/256/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/256/task/256/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/257/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/257/task/257/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/258/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/258/task/258/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/259/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/259/task/259/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/26/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/26/task/26/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/260/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/260/task/260/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/261/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/261/task/261/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/262/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/262/task/262/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/263/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/263/task/263/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/264/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/264/task/264/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/265/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/265/task/265/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/266/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/266/task/266/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/267/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/267/task/267/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/268/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/268/task/268/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/cwd: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/root: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/exe: No such file or directory
ls: reading directory ./proc/2681/net: Invalid argument
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/ns/net: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/ns/uts: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/ns/ipc: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/ns/mnt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/task/2681/cwd: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/task/2681/root: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/task/2681/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/task/2681/ns/net: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/task/2681/ns/uts: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/task/2681/ns/ipc: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/2681/task/2681/ns/mnt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/269/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/269/task/269/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/27/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/27/task/27/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/270/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/270/task/270/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/271/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/271/task/271/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/272/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/272/task/272/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/273/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/273/task/273/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/274/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/274/task/274/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/275/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/275/task/275/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/276/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/276/task/276/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/277/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/277/task/277/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/278/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/278/task/278/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/279/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/279/task/279/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/28/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/28/task/28/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/281/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/281/task/281/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/282/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/282/task/282/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/283/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/283/task/283/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/284/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/284/task/284/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/285/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/285/task/285/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/286/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/286/task/286/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/287/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/287/task/287/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/29/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/29/task/29/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/299/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/299/task/299/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3/task/3/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/30/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/30/task/30/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/301/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/301/task/301/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/302/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/302/task/302/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3086/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3086/task/3086/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3087/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3087/task/3087/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3099/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3099/task/3099/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/31/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/31/task/31/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3100/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3100/task/3100/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/32/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/32/task/32/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/323/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/323/task/323/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/324/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/324/task/324/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/33/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/33/task/33/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/34/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/34/task/34/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3464/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3464/task/3464/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3465/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3465/task/3465/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/35/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/35/task/35/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3502/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/3502/task/3502/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/36/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/36/task/36/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/37/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/37/task/37/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/375/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/375/task/375/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/376/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/376/task/376/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/377/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/377/task/377/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/379/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/379/task/379/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/38/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/38/task/38/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/381/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/381/task/381/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/382/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/382/task/382/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/383/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/383/task/383/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/384/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/384/task/384/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/385/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/385/task/385/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/386/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/386/task/386/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/387/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/387/task/387/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/388/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/388/task/388/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/389/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/389/task/389/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/39/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/39/task/39/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/390/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/390/task/390/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/391/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/391/task/391/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/392/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/392/task/392/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/393/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/393/task/393/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/394/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/394/task/394/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/395/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/395/task/395/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/396/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/396/task/396/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/397/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/397/task/397/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/398/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/398/task/398/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/399/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/399/task/399/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/40/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/40/task/40/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/400/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/400/task/400/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/401/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/401/task/401/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/402/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/402/task/402/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/403/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/403/task/403/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/404/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/404/task/404/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/405/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/405/task/405/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/406/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/406/task/406/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/407/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/407/task/407/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/408/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/408/task/408/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/409/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/409/task/409/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/41/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/41/task/41/exe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot read symbolic link ./proc/410/exe: No such file or directory
```

How to deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "deal with" this, it's normal.

`/proc` is a virtual filesystem, as are `/dev` and `/sys` (if present), meant to present system information and provide a file-like way to change the system configuration - that is, those files aren't *really* on your hard disk.

http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

All sorts of broken links and loops and I/O errors can and will occur if you try to iterate over `/proc` it as if it were a "regular" folder, because... it's not.

So, the answer is: you don't.

If you want, you *can* silence the errors by redirecting them to `/dev/null`:

`$ ls -alRc 2> /dev/null`

For the sake of experimentation, notice how doing a `cat /dev/null` afterwards does *not* print your errors - because as we said `/dev` is a virtual filesystem and `/dev/null` is not a real file but... the closest analogue to a black hole you'll find in a Linux system :)